# jQuery FadeOut function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I'm trying to add a fadeOut function which links to another. [CLICK HERE](http://iamnatesmithen.com/jukebox/index.php) At present I have a flashing logo. When the user clicks on the logo, the flashing stops, has a slight delay then slowly fades Out. Is there anyone out there that is able to correct me on the code I have pasted below?

```
    <script>
         $(document).ready(function(){
         $("#center-gif").click(function(){
            $('#center-gif').hide();
            $('#center-img').show();
            });
         $('#center-img').click(function(){
            $('#center-img').hide();
            $('#center-img-gif').show();
        });
         $('flash-link').click(function(){
            $('center-img').fadeOut(5000);
         });
    });
        </script>
```

Comment: Can you add a JS Bin of this? I'm lazy today.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/ it gives you the possibility to work in a testing environment. So others don't have to test the code in their environment.

Comment: your fadeOut(5000) declaration is true but, element selectors are wrong, check my answer than you will understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to access element with `class`/`id`; you must always define `.` and `#` these at the begining, like css.

Some Examples:

```
$('img').fadeOut();//selects all img elements
$('.img').fadeOut();//selects all elements with class="img"

$('myClass').fadeOut(); //false
$('.myClass').fadeOut(); //true

$('myId').fadeOut(); //false
$('#myId').fadeOut(); //true
```

Here is working jQuery for your question with less code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("img").click(function(){
        var takeId = $(this).attr('id');//takes clicked element's id

        $('img').hide();//hides all content

        $('#'+takeId).show();
        //matches clicked element's id with element and shows that
     });

     $('#flash-link').click(function(){//define '#' id declaration here
        $('#center-img').fadeOut(5000,//new function after fadeOut complete
          function() {
             window.open('url','http://iamnatesmithen.com/jukebox/dancers.php');
             return false;
          });
        );
     });
});
```

Comment: i've attempted this method and it just navigates to a blank screen??

Comment: i have added method to open a link at same window

Comment: Right, sorry to be a pain, but have you tested it bcos it's not doing the transition, i've updated the code on my site...

Comment: btw for your information; i realised that, i forgot to add id symbol here $(takeId).show(); . i corrected that with this $('#'+takeId).show();

Answer (score 0):

So I assume your problem is that that image does not fade out, right?

This could solve it:

First of all change your `.click()`-functions to that:

```
$().click( function(event) {
    // cour code
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

And than change the last one like that:

```
$('#flash-link').click( function(event) {
    $('#center-img').fadeOut( 5000, function() {
        window.location.href = 'jukebox/dancers.php';
    });
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

I didn't test that, but it should work. What it does is: It fades out the image and calls a function when ready. This functions then redirects to your next page.

The `event.preventDefault();` will tell the browser not to delegate the `click`-event. If you don't put it there, the browser opens the anchor without waiting for any JavaScript to execute.

#### Note

When you want to select an element with an ID use this selector: `$('#[id]')`as this selector `$('html')`works only with HTML-elements.

Comment: this wont work because, there are no elements $('flash-link') and $('center-img')

Comment: As I said, I didn't test it and just copied the code from the OP and I didn't recognize it. Argh. You're absolutely right. They should be IDs. I corrected it in my answer.